# Need to create a function that will cycle through an object that contains 5 questions but unsure why my function is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HW assignment to create a time JS code quiz. I have 5 questions stored in an object and created a function to cycle through the questions but in my code the question's will not proceed after answering the first one right. I was just hoping if anyone could spot the error I made on why the questions won't proceed.

//Object Containers for the questions

```
let questions =[
{question: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include: ",choiceA: "string",choiceB: "boolean",choiceC: "alerts",choiceD: "numbers",correctAnswer: "c"},

{question: "The conditions in an if/else statement is encolsed with:",choiceA: "quotes",choiceB: "curly brackets",choiceC: "paretheseses",choiceD: "square bracekts",correctAnswer: "c"},

{question: "An array in JavaScript can be used to store:",choiceA: "numbers & strings",choiceB: "other arrays",choiceC: "booleans",choiceD: "all of the above",correctAnswer: "d"},

{question: "String values must be enclosed within ____ when being assigned to variables",choiceA: "commas",choiceB: "curly brackets",choiceC: "quotes",choiceD: "parethesis",correctAnswer: "a"},

{question: "A very useful tool during development and debugging for printing content to the dubugger is:",choiceA: "JavaScript",choiceB: "terminal/bash",choiceC: "for loop",choiceD: "console.log",correctAnswer: "d"},
];

var quizIntroEl = document.getElementById("quizIntro");
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");

var quizStartMenuEl = document.getElementById("quizStartMenu");
var timerEl = document.getElementById("timer");
var questionBox = document.getElementById("questionBox");
var askQuestionEl = document.getElementById("askQuestion");
var buttonA = document.getElementById("a");
var buttonB = document.getElementById("b");
var buttonC = document.getElementById("c");
var buttonD = document.getElementById("d");

var gameOver = document.getElementById("gameOver");
var scoreListEl = document.getElementById("scoreList");
var initialsEl = document.getElementById("initials");
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

var highScoresContainer = document.getElementById("highScoresContainer");
var highScorePage = document.getElementById("highScorePage");
var highScoreHeader = document.getElementById("highScoreHeader");
var highScoreInitials = document.getElementById("highScoreInitials");
var highScoreScore = document.getElementById("highScoreScore");

var endGame = document.getElementById("endGame");
var playAgain = document.getElementById("playAgain");
var clearHighScore = document.getElementById("clearHighScore");

var finalQuestionIndex = questions.length;
var initialquestionIndex = 0;var timeleft = 61;
var timerInterval;var score = 0;
var correctAnswerEl;
var currentQuestion = questions[initialquestionIndex];

function quizQuestions() {
if (initialquestionIndex === finalQuestionIndex) {
return showScore();
}

currentQuestion;
askQuestionEl.innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
buttonA.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceA;
buttonB.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceB;
buttonC.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceC;
buttonD.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceD;
}

function startQuiz() {
quizIntroEl.classList.add("hide");
startButton.classList.add("hide");
questionBox.classList.remove("hide");
quizQuestions(); 

timerInterval = setInterval(function() {     
timeleft--;     
timerEl.textContent = "Time: " + timeleft;      
if(timeleft === 0) {         
clearInterval(timerInterval);         
showScore();     
} 
}, 1000)  
}


function showScore() {
quizIntroEl.classList.add("hide");
gameOver.style.display = "flex";
scoreListEl.classList.remove("hide");
clearInterval(timerInterval);
highScoreInitials.value = "";
scoreListEl.innerHTML = "Your score is: " + score + " of " + questions.length;
}

function correctAnswer(answer) {
correctAnswerEl = currentQuestion.correctAnswer;

if (answer === correctAnswerEl && initialquestionIndex !== finalQuestionIndex) {
    alert("Correct!");
    initialquestionIndex++;
    quizQuestions();
} else if (answer !== correctAnswerEl && initialquestionIndex !== finalQuestionIndex) {
    alert("Wrong!")
    timeleft = timeleft - 10;
    initialquestionIndex++;
    quizQuestions();
} else {
    showScore();
}

startButton.addEventListener("click",startQuiz);
```

This is what I have currently made. The startQuiz function works but I cannot get the quizQuestions function to cycle through to the next question. I thought I should include all the DOM elements I made so all context can be shown.

Comment: Is there an error in your console? Please include your html so we can have a minimal reproducible example to attempt to recreate the problem.

Comment: `var currentQuestion = questions[initialquestionIndex];` that needs to be inside/called from the quizQuestions function, or the currentQuestion will never change.

Comment: It would be helpful to format the code and include the HTML it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

well in `startQuiz()` you call `quizQuestions()` so the first question appears but the second question should appear when you choose any of the options but your buttons associated with options are not calling the `correctAnswer()`

```
buttonA.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceA;
buttonB.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceB;
buttonC.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceC;
buttonD.innerHTML = currentQuestion.choiceD;
```

so these buttons should call the `correctAnswer()`
and `correctAnswer()` will populate the next questions

make this little code change  `currentQuestion = questions[initialquestionIndex];` just add this in you function

```
function correctAnswer(answer) {
correctAnswerEl = currentQuestion.correctAnswer;

if (answer === correctAnswerEl && initialquestionIndex !== finalQuestionIndex) {
    alert("Correct!");
    initialquestionIndex++;
    currentQuestion = questions[initialquestionIndex];
    quizQuestions();
} else if (answer !== correctAnswerEl && initialquestionIndex !== finalQuestionIndex) {
    alert("Wrong!")
    timeleft = timeleft - 10;
    initialquestionIndex++;
     currentQuestion = questions[initialquestionIndex];
    quizQuestions();
} else {
    showScore();
}
```

the score variable you are trying to use is defined nowhere
so initialize it first like other vars

```
var score = 0
```

then in your `correctAnswer()`

you can increment `score` it if its correct

```
function correctAnswer(answer) {
correctAnswerEl = currentQuestion.correctAnswer;

if (answer === correctAnswerEl && initialquestionIndex !== finalQuestionIndex) {
    alert("Correct!");
    // by whatever value you want to increment score here i'm using 1
    score += 1
    initialquestionIndex++;
    currentQuestion = questions[initialquestionIndex];
    quizQuestions();
} else if (answer !== correctAnswerEl && initialquestionIndex !== finalQuestionIndex) {
    alert("Wrong!")
    timeleft = timeleft - 10;
    initialquestionIndex++;
     currentQuestion = questions[initialquestionIndex];
    quizQuestions();
} else {
    showScore();
}
```

JUST A GOOD SUGGESTION

and also you are using global vriables which is not a good practice consider using `let` instead of `var` and pass argument to function rather than accessing them directly

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue of the questions cycling! :) It's not not displaying the correct score but one problem at a time! You're awesome!

Comment: @tokugawa i just edited my solution to solve score problem kindly do check

Comment: I had score initialized in my global variables! But just to ask due to your comment should I move it from the global variable to the local function? And that did fix the problem! I didn't realize I wasn't incrementing the score!

Comment: @tokugawa well using global variables is not a good practice as see like you forget to increment your score there were some other problems as well. Global variables lead to bugs and are too confusing if project gets bigger. Using local `let` variables are recommended but it will take you to refactor your code. So to answer your ques yes you should use local variables. : )